# Joining two files on a field

Tags: awk, join

I need to compare two files and based on comparison I need to add new column in first file.
**Column C is the primary key**.

```
A,B,C,D
1,1990,I001,2473264
2,1991,I002,2473265
3,1992,I004,2473266
4,1993,6050,912432
5,1994,6003,912433
```

SECOND FILE

```
A,B
I001,2.3 GHz
I002,2.3 GHz
I004,2.3 GHz
6050,1.8 GHz
6003,850 MHz
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,1990,2.3 GHz,I001,2473264
2,1991,2.3 GHz,I002,2473265
3,1992,2.3 GHz,I004,2473266
4,1993,1.8 GHz,6050,912432
5,1994,850 MHz,6003,912433
```

This code is working fine, but if the record is not matched it is skipping the row from first file. But I don’t want it to get skipped and append 0 or NA in that column.

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}a[$3]{print $0","a[$3]}' test2 test1
```

```
A,B,C,D
1,1990,I001,2473264
2,1991,I002,2473265
3,1992,I004,2473266
4,1993,6050,912432
5,1994,6003,912433
6,1995,6004,21234
```

Expected Output:

```
1,1990,I001,2473264,2.3 GHz
2,1991,I002,2473265,2.3 GHz
3,1992,I004,2473266,2.3 GHz
4,1993,6050,912432,1.8 GHz
5,1994,6003,912433,850 MHz
6,1995,6004,21234,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `awk` to

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} FNR!=1{print $0","(a[$3]?a[$3]:"NA")}' SECOND FIRST
1,1990,I001,2473264,2.3 GHz
2,1991,I002,2473265,2.3 GHz
3,1992,I004,2473266,2.3 GHz
4,1993,6050,912432,1.8 GHz
5,1994,6003,912433,850 MHz
6,1995,6004,21234,NA
```

To get your first desired result:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} FNR!=1{$3=(a[$3]?a[$3]:"NA")","$3; print}' OFS=, SECOND FIRST
1,1990,2.3 GHz,I001,2473264
2,1991,2.3 GHz,I002,2473265
3,1992,2.3 GHz,I004,2473266
4,1993,1.8 GHz,6050,912432
5,1994,850 MHz,6003,912433
6,1995,NA,6004,21234
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `awk` program is correct if we modify it to *unconditionally* use

```
print $0","( a[$3] ? a[$3] : 0 )
```

instead of using

```
print $0","a[$3]
```

when `a[$3]` is non-zero or empty.
That is, use a zero if the `a[$3]` field is zero or empty, otherwise use `a[$3]`.

In other words,

```
awk -F, -v OFS=',' 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$2; next } FNR > 1 { print $0, (a[$3] ? a[$3] : 0) }' fileB fileA
```

We use `FNR > 1` here to skip the header.

---

Using `join`:

```
$ join -t , -1 3 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2 fileA fileB
1,1990,I001,2473264,2.3 GHz
2,1991,I002,2473265,2.3 GHz
3,1992,I004,2473266,2.3 GHz
4,1993,6050,912432,1.8 GHz
5,1994,6003,912433,850 MHz
```

If the files are not sorted on the joining key, then (in a shell that support process substitutions):

```
$ join -t , -1 3 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2 <( sort -t, -k3,3 fileA ) <( sort fileB )
5,1994,6003,912433,850 MHz
4,1993,6050,912432,1.8 GHz
1,1990,I001,2473264,2.3 GHz
2,1991,I002,2473265,2.3 GHz
3,1992,I004,2473266,2.3 GHz
```

The `join` will perform an `INNER JOIN` operation on the two files. The `-t ,` tells `join` that commas are the field delimiter and we pick the third field as the join key in the first file with `-1 3` (the first field in the second file is assumed to be the key, unless we use `-2 N` for same other field `N` in that file).

The `-o` flag tells `join` what fields we'd like to include in the output and from what file (`x.y` means column `y` from file `x`).

`join` is a very fast operation, but it *requires* that the input files are sorted on the joining key (we were just lucky with the first example above).  The final output in the second example above is unsorted with respect to the *first* field, but you may easily fix that by piping it through `sort -k1,1n`.

---

For the second scenario, with a mismatch,

```
$ join -t, -1 3 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2 -a 1 -e 0  <( sort -t, -k3,3 fileA ) <( sort fileB )
5,1994,6003,912433,850 MHz
6,1995,6004,21234,0
4,1993,6050,912432,1.8 GHz
A,B,C,D,0
1,1990,I001,2473264,2.3 GHz
2,1991,I002,2473265,2.3 GHz
3,1992,I004,2473266,2.3 GHz
```

By adding `-a 1 -e 0` we ask `join` to always output all fields from the first file `(-a 1`) and to insert zeroes for every field that is missing in the second file.

As you can see, we now get the correct result, but the header from the first file is also included (because we asked for it).  If you want to remove the headers from the data of both files (and sort the result), then

```
$ join -t, -1 3 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2 -e 0 -a1  <( tail -n +2 fileA | sort -t, -k3,3 ) <( tail -n +2 fileB | sort ) | sort -k1,1n
1,1990,I001,2473264,2.3 GHz
2,1991,I002,2473265,2.3 GHz
3,1992,I004,2473266,2.3 GHz
4,1993,6050,912432,1.8 GHz
5,1994,6003,912433,850 MHz
6,1995,6004,21234,0
```

This command would actually work for both scenarios.

Comment: fairly your `awk` solution is almost in my answer

Comment: The `awk` code outputs an unexpected `0` in the header:  `A,B,C,D,0`

Comment: @agc So it does. I have fixed that by ignoring the header of the second file.

Comment: @αғsнιη There's only so many ways to do this in `awk`. At least I'm using slightly different syntax and `OFS`, which makes it a bit different. I did not read your answer before answering (and wrote it initially as a `join`-only answer, not `awk`).

Answer (score 0):

Using *GNU* `join` with the extended data and the *first* output format, plus `echo` and `tail` to replace the header, (because `join` gets confused by inconsistent headers):

```
echo A,B,C,D,E
join -t ',' --header --nocheck-order test1 test2 \
     -a 1 -e NA -1 3 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2,1.3,1.4 | tail -n +2
```

Output:

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,1990,2.3 GHz,I001,2473264
2,1991,2.3 GHz,I002,2473265
3,1992,2.3 GHz,I004,2473266
4,1993,1.8 GHz,6050,912432
5,1994,850 MHz,6003,912433
6,1995,NA,6004,21234
```